# Pythonic way to log console output to a log file in Spyder python editor

Tags: python, python-3.x, logging, console, anaconda

I am using Anaconda and Spyder as my python environment and editor. I just learnt some very basic way to log simple print information to a log file. But it seems quite unpythonic. What I have done is down below:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import logging


logger = logging.getLogger('test2')
logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

formatter = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s')

fh = logging.FileHandler('test2.log')
fh.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
fh.setFormatter(formatter)
logger.addHandler(fh)

ch = logging.StreamHandler()
ch.setLevel(logging.ERROR)
ch.setFormatter(formatter)
logger.addHandler(ch)

X = np.array([1,2,3])
print(X)
logger.info(f'{X}')

str1 = 'hello world'
print(str1)
logger.info(str1)

df = pd.DataFrame({'col1': np.arange(40),
                   'col2': np.tile([0,1,2,3],10)
                    })
print(df)
logger.info(f'{df}')
```

Basically whenever I feel the need to print something, I have to add one extra line of code to log it. It may not seem like a problem in this example, but if I have to print 500+ lines of stuff in a super long script, it can be very inefficient.

My questions are the following:

1) Is there any workaround with a few lines of code so that whenever I print something to the Spyder console it will be logged to the external file? I'd like to see how it is done.

2) If the python script is run by first reading it from an external txt file and execute it, does this make logging any different than the case where the script is run normally?

3) Since I am using Anaconda as Python environment and Spyder as IDE, does this make logging any different than using other python editor and other Python environment?

Thank you in advance

EDIT1: I tried using the following code

```
ch = logging.StreamHandler(stream=sys.stdout)
ch.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
```

but unfortunately whatever printed on Spyder console does not get copied to the external file. Maybe I have missed something.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

import logging
import sys

logger = logging.getLogger('test3')
logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

formatter = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s')

fh = logging.FileHandler('test3.log')
fh.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
fh.setFormatter(formatter)
logger.addHandler(fh)

ch = logging.StreamHandler(stream=sys.stdout)
ch.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
ch.setFormatter(formatter)
logger.addHandler(ch)

X = np.array([1,2,3])
print(X)

str1 = 'hello world'
print(str1)

df = pd.DataFrame({'col1': np.arange(40),
                   'col2': np.tile([0,1,2,3],10)
                    })
print(df)
```

Comment: The stream handler looks misconfigured, try `ch = logging.StreamHandler(stream=sys.stdout)` and `ch.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)`

Comment: @hoefling Thanks for your reply. I think I will try yours in a separate file just to see how it plays out. But what I did was simply following the first session of https://docs.python.org/3/howto/logging-cookbook.html. I thought the cookbook is official and therefore is correct?!

Comment: The logging cookbook is just a collection of examples. In the example you selected, only the records with levels `ERROR` and `CRITICAL` will be printed.

Comment: @hoeffling I changed according to your suggestion(see the code under EDIT1), but whatever printed on console won't get copied to the log file unless I explicitly typed `logger.info(some string)`. Did I miss something?

Comment: You mean Spyder's interactive console? It's just an IPython console, so any IPython solution should work. See e.g. [How to log IPython history to text file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16858724/how-to-log-ipython-history-to-text-file/39413200) etc.